# Web-service client on Websphere throws NullPointer on method calling

Tags: java, spring, websphere, jax-ws

We've been using

- jaxws-spring
- WebSphere 8.5.5.2

for our web-services interactions, and now we get stuck with such "cause" when we call any web-method on the client-side -

```
ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause appServlet: 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
.....
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1363)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1089)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.java:680)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:626)
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:946)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils.getJAXBContext(JAXBUtils.java:445)
at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext.getJAXBContext(JAXBDSContext.java:228)
at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext.getJAXBContext(JAXBDSContext.java:161)
at org.apache.axis2.datasource.jaxb.JAXBDSContext.marshal(JAXBDSContext.java:396)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.impl.JAXBBlockImpl._outputFromBO(JAXBBlockImpl.java:189)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.BlockImpl.outputTo(BlockImpl.java:371)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.BlockImpl.serialize(BlockImpl.java:295)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:781)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:967)
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:283)
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:245)
at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:207)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
```

Web-service client initialisation comes out with no any errors -

```
URL service_endpoint;
service_endpoint = new URL(endpoint);
service = new UDHandlersServiceImpl(service_endpoint, SERVICE_QNAME).getUDHandlersServiceImplPort();
```

NullPointerException occurs after calling any method of "service". And it doesn't even reach server side - because it doesn't have any logs there. Furthermore - such situation occurs only on the WebSphere - we deployed our client application on the Tomcat (server remained on websphere) and it worked fine. One more thing - SoapUI does not have any problems interacting with server side too.

We tried to switch classLoadings to parentLast for client application - with no success.

Also I can't even find sources for "org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils.getJAXBContext(JAXBUtils.java:445)". I googled it and didn't find this version of JAXBUtils. But even if i did, i think, it wouldnt be useful...

I hope someone can help us with that unobvious problem.
Thanks beforehand.

### ===== updated======

When we remove jaxb libraries from endorsed dir (or appServer/classes) problem seems to disappear but in case of arising webExceptions(faults) server throws

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl incompatible with com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext
at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.<clinit>(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:565)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:237)
```

and returns no answer to the client.

Comment: Do you have axis2 libraries in your client app? Maybe try to remove them, as they are already provided in WebSphere.

Comment: No, we don't. Actually we don't have package "org.apache.axis2" among client libraries and despite of that "WAS" uses it. And it happens because, as you said, it's provided in WAS. Thanks for answering.

Comment: With "remove jaxb libraries from endorsed dir", do you mean remove jaxb-api.jar from AppServer/endorsed_apis directory?

Comment: I have the same problem but I can't remove those libraries from the endorsed dir because there are lot of applications running on the same server. Did you find another alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've realized that our exceptions didn't contain 3 required methods -

```
//============required==================
public DocumentValidationException(String message, ErrorsBean errorsBean, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
    this.errorsBean = errorsBean;
}

public ErrorsBean getFaultInfo() {
    return errorsBean;
}

public DocumentValidationException(String message, ErrorsBean errorsBean) {
    super(message);
    this.errorsBean = errorsBean;
}
//======================================
```

so, now it does.

And also we had some wrong target namespaces in it at the @WebFault annotations.
Here is the link with similar problem - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014076927#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014083314